# Repeated Selection of 2 random options, how to model it

Tags: survey, choice-modeling

### Probelem/Idea

I am thinking of using an analysis with a methodology similar to the one ESPN is using to rank NBA players:

```
... a system where voters are shown two players and asked to choose which 
will have the better season based on quality and quantity of play. That makes 
it easier to directly compare the top players to each other and determine 
where they relatively rank ...
```

You can read a bit more about this [here](https://www.espn.com/nba/insider/story/_/id/32238053/nbarank-2021-learned-decade-ranking-world-best-players)

### Question

I would think this would be modeled as a discrete choice analysis? but I am uncertain, as a second example lets say that I want so see how people value different animal species and I have 20 of them If I repeatedly asked many people which of 2 random species they liked the best, how would I end up with a ranking? how would I test it's power?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[This page goes](https://www.questionpro.com/tour/pairwise-ranking-and-comparison.html) into how to use pairwise comparisons to derive rankings. Essentially, you create a matrix of all the pairwise comparisons, and the "count" the number of matchups that each item won, and rank based on this score. If you google "Paired Comparison Analysis" you'll get a ton of resources on this.

I imagine that ESPN isn't comparing EVERY player to EVERY player, as this just isn't feasible. I can find any resources on what to do with missing data, but I doubt there is one 'correct' answer. When thing you could do is dynamically change the comparisons over the course of the study. So, you could "split" the data into groups based on your prior beliefs about rankings, and get full pairwise comparisons within those matrices.

Then, you could take the top performers of each group and compare them to the lowest in the group above, and see if you should swap them. This is essentially what British soccer leagues do by moving teams up a league or down a league at the end of each season.

You could also essentially implement a sorting algorithm, where you start with a set order (probably based on priors) and then compare each person to the player directly above or below them in the current rankings. If they beat the person above them, you move them up, if they lose, you move them down. Then you loop through this process for all players until you get a convergence to a sorted list.

This isn't a statistical, probabilistic test, so I doubt there is a good way to test the power. You could probably estimate some error bounds for any individual player based on the proportion of test they won/lost with Variance = (p)(1-p).